# How do I optimize this mysql query with nested joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Below is my query which I need to optimize.

```
SELECT
        UPPER(IFNULL(op.supplier_payment_method,s.default_payment_method)) AS Payment_Method,
        op.supplier_payment_date AS Payment_Date,
        Date_format(IFNULL(op.supplier_payment_date,op.ship_date),'%M %Y') AS Payment_Month,
        s.supplier_name AS Farm,
        op.sub_order_id AS Order_num,
        Date_format(op.ship_date,'%b-%d-%Y') AS Ship_Date,
        op.farm_credit AS Farm_Credit,
        op.credit_memo AS Credit_Memo,
        op.credit_description AS Credit_Description,
        opb.boxes AS Box_Type,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.box_charge,2)) AS Box_Charge,
        op.invoice_num AS Invoice_num,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.invoice_amt,2)) AS Invoice_Amt,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.total_invoice_amt,2)) AS Total_Invoice_Amt,
        CONCAT(op.UM_qty,' ',op.UM_type) AS St_Bu_Qty,
        op.PO_Product_Name AS Invoice_desc,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT((op.price_um*op.um_qty),2)) AS Cost_product_cms,
        op.supplier_invoice_note AS Supplier_Invoice_Notes,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.cms_invoice_cost,2)) AS CMS_Invoice_diff,
        CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.total_farm_cost,2)) AS Farm_Cost
    FROM 
        orders_products op
        INNER JOIN 
            suppliers s ON s.supplier_id = op.supplier_name
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    sub_order_id, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(box_type_qty,' ',bo.box_option_name) SEPARATOR ', ') AS boxes
                FROM
                    order_products_boxes opb
                    INNER JOIN box_options bo ON bo.id=opb.box_type_id
                GROUP BY
                    opb.sub_order_id
            ) opb ON opb.sub_order_id = op.sub_order_id
    WHERE
        op.order_active=0
        AND op.ship_date>='2013-03-01'
        AND op.ship_date<='2013-04_01'
    ORDER BY op.ship_date DESC
```

As you can see, the query comprises of 4 tables, each containing around 20k-30k rows each.  So as soon as I add in the sub-query, the query becomes exceptionally slow. It takes approx 1.5mins to fetch just 500 rows of record. Is there a way to speed things up within a single query?

Comment: Why do you have a SELECT statement as a JOIN argument?  The information in this SELECT will not be returned in the query results.

Comment: Add `op.order_active=0` condition in the first `ON` condition between table `order_products` and `suppliers`, One more suggestion try using `BETWEEN` clause for your date comparison in the where clause...

Comment: @Richard That's because I need to do a GROUP_CONCAT to fetch the desired result, and I can't do that within the actual result set, as then I'll end up with just one row

Comment: in your first INNER JOIN, should the statement be: s.supplier_id = op.supplier_id ?  You have op.supplier_name

Comment: @Richard umm yeh, that will be supplier_name....the column name is a bit wrong but since this table already contains a lot of data and is referenced is a lot of places, I would rather keep it as it is

Comment: The other possibility is to add the group_concat as a user-defined function that returns the information that you require, which will simplify the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your left-join query that pre-concatenates the sub-box options is querying the ENTIRE DATABASE FIRST, then only joins to those that are within the criteria you are limiting for the outer WHERE clause.  It may be a little more effort, but pull the same outer criteria into your inner query should significantly help.  As for doing a field-level sql-select on a per-every-row basis could be a performance killer.

You should only need to change at the "FROM" clause...

```
from
   orders_products op
      INNER JOIN suppliers s 
         ON op.supplier_name = s.supplier_id 
      LEFT JOIN
         ( SELECT 
                 opb2.sub_order_id, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(box_type_qty,' ',bo.box_option_name) SEPARATOR ', ') AS boxes
              FROM
                 orders_products op2
                    JOIN order_products_boxes opb2
                       on op2.sub_order_id = opb2.sub_order_id
                       INNER JOIN box_options bo 
                          ON opb2.box_type_id = bo.id
              WHERE
                     op2.order_active = 0
                 AND op2.ship_date >= '2013-03-01'
                 AND op2.ship_date <= '2013-04_01'
              GROUP BY
                 opb2.sub_order_id  ) opb 
         ON op.sub_order_id = opb.sub_order_id
WHERE
       op.order_active = 0
   AND op.ship_date >= '2013-03-01'
   AND op.ship_date <= '2013-04_01'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm....I was thinking about somehow using the order id restriction to speed things up, but I never thought about executing the same thing within the sub query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    UPPER(IFNULL(op.supplier_payment_method,s.default_payment_method)) AS Payment_Method,
    op.supplier_payment_date AS Payment_Date,
    Date_format(IFNULL(op.supplier_payment_date,op.ship_date),'%M %Y') AS Payment_Month,
    s.supplier_name AS Farm,
    op.sub_order_id AS Order_num,
    Date_format(op.ship_date,'%b-%d-%Y') AS Ship_Date,
    op.farm_credit AS Farm_Credit,
    op.credit_memo AS Credit_Memo,
    op.credit_description AS Credit_Description,
     (
            SELECT 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(box_type_qty,' ',bo.box_option_name) SEPARATOR ', ') 
            FROM
                order_products_boxes opb
                INNER JOIN box_options bo ON bo.id=opb.box_type_id
            GROUP BY
                opb.sub_order_id
        ) AS Box_Type,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.box_charge,2)) AS Box_Charge,
    op.invoice_num AS Invoice_num,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.invoice_amt,2)) AS Invoice_Amt,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.total_invoice_amt,2)) AS Total_Invoice_Amt,
    CONCAT(op.UM_qty,' ',op.UM_type) AS St_Bu_Qty,
    op.PO_Product_Name AS Invoice_desc,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT((op.price_um*op.um_qty),2)) AS Cost_product_cms,
    op.supplier_invoice_note AS Supplier_Invoice_Notes,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.cms_invoice_cost,2)) AS CMS_Invoice_diff,
    CONCAT('$',FORMAT(op.total_farm_cost,2)) AS Farm_Cost
FROM 
    orders_products op
    INNER JOIN 
        suppliers s ON s.supplier_id = op.supplier_name
    LEFT JOIN

                order_products_boxes opb (
                INNER JOIN box_options bo ON bo.id=opb.box_type_id
        ) opb ON opb.sub_order_id = op.sub_order_id
WHERE
    op.order_active=0
    AND op.ship_date>='2013-03-01'
    AND op.ship_date<='2013-04_01'
ORDER BY op.ship_date DESC
```

Comment: The problem is the group_concat that needs to be placed within a subquery. Basically, there is a box table with box name, and a per product mapping table to map the box by id to the order and the quantity of that box, so to get the box name and quantity together and then display them in the same field in result set, I have to do a group_concat

Comment: Got this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( INNER JOIN box_options bo ON bo.id=opb.box_type_id ) o' at line 36

Comment: Remove the opb before the ON in the LEFT JOIN.